# Angularjs set value to text box on click of button

Tags: angularjs

I have following UI in my angularjs project[image]

on click of button in front of textbox i am calling one API whose code is

```
$scope.generateAppId = function(){
    var reqData = {};
    var res = $http.post('http://192.168.1.30:8090/apps/createappid', $scope.reqData);
    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.message = data;
        $scope.appId = data.appId
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This is the reponse data on successful API call

```
{
id: null
name: null
appId: "c5b09133-eb40-4b90-b6de-5cfd054b2de9"
secret: null
domain: null
}
```

Now i want to set value **appId** in JSON response to the textbox.

Comment: so initially app -id will be empty.and when you click the button appid  should be displayed inside textbox ??am i rght??

Comment: You should just be able to use `ng-model="appId"` since you're exposing `data.appId` directly on the scope.

Comment: @roxid yes on click of button i want to display it inside textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couldn't you have a seperate $scope variable for the textbox and have that variable as the model in the textbox?

You could set the variable to be an empty string when not required to show anything and then set the variable to $scope.appId

`$scope.textbox = ''`

`<input type='textbox' ng-model='textbox' name='textbox'>`

then

`$scope.textbox = $scope.appId`

Answer (score 1):

Please read the tutorial at:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

Bind the controller to your html and do:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="appId">
```